# Get the state parameters from OAuth callback in passportjs

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am trying to send state parameters to the Oauth and then catch them in the callback, but I cannot make it work. So does passportjs support such a functionality?

My idea is to send an id as state parameter to the Oauth and then on the callback depending on the id from the state parameters sent back to my app I want to do a proper redirect.

In the Twitter strategy I have enabled

```
passReqToCallback: true,
state: true
```

My request should look like this:

```
app.get('/auth/twitter/:gameId/:url',
    function(req, res){
        try {
            var json = JSON.stringify({gameId: req.params.gameId, url: req.params.url});
            var encodedValues = base64url(json);
            console.log('encodedValues:'+encodedValues)
            passport.authenticate('twitter', {state:encodedValues})
        }catch (e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
);
```

then on the callback

```
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', function(req, res, next) {
try{
    //get the state params from the res uri/body
    //decode the state params
    //redirect depending on the state.gameId
}catch(e){
    console.log('twitter exception:'+e);
}}));
```

I already know that I can save the id in a session, but I would like to know if there is a session less way to do it by passing this information from url since it is not sensitive.

Thanks

Comment: Did you work out how to do this? Looks like Twitter support OAuth 1 but not 2 so don't support the state param.

Comment: Not yet. I am planning to use session to store the param since tha lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

With oAuth 2.0 you don't have to rely on any type of session for this. The way you pass in state on the `/auth/twitter/:gameId/:url` route, you would be able to access the state on your callback with `req.query.state`.

In case someone else runs into problems, when trying to pass application state through the oAuth progress, this is how I solved it in my Node-app:

Since I want to redirect the user to different locations, based on the location the user came from before entering the authentication screen, I built different routes for accessing the authentication screen, and passed different state along depending on which route was hit. Like this:

```js
router.get('/google/io', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    state: 'io'
}));

router.get('/google/de', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    state: 'de'
}));
```

So if my users access the auth screen coming from my page using the .io domain, my state parameter will carry the value of 'io', and if a user accesses the auth screen coming from the .de version of my page, the state parameter will carry the value of 'de'. On successful authentication, I can then just extract the value from `req.query.state`, and redirect them back to `mypage.de` or `mypage.io`